# refresh viewmodel on intervals mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a view with a List of ViewModels that is based on data from my database. I present this list, but I want to the list to be refreshed on a given interval(5 secs) as the data in the database changes. I have a Action in my controller that update the ViewModels. I use MVC 3 and Razor. 
I guess some JavaScript/jQuery is needed.

My script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var hdRaceId = $("#hdRaceId");

    setInterval("GetList()", 5000);
    function GetList() {
        $.get("/Timer/Update/?id=" + hdRaceId.val());
    }
```

My Action in my controller:

```
        public ActionResult Update(int id)
    {
        var raceintermediates = RaceIntermediateModel.GetRaceintermediatesForRace(id);
        return View("Speaker", raceintermediates);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to refresh some part of the DOM you need to define a success callback to your AJAX request. Like this:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    var hdRaceId = $('#hdRaceId').val(); 
    var updateUrl = '@Url.Action("Update", "Timer")';
    $.get(updateUrl, { id: hdRaceId }, function(result) {
        $('#someDivId').html(result);
    });
}, 5000);
```

where you have some div that will host the partial view results:

```
<div id="someDivId"></div>
```

also some browsers like IE might cache GET requests. In order to avoid this you could use the following:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    var hdRaceId = $('#hdRaceId').val(); 
    var updateUrl = '@Url.Action("Update", "Timer")';
    $.ajax({
        url: updateUrl,
        type: 'GET',
        data: { id: hdRaceId }, 
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            $('#someDivId').html(result);
        }
    });
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout(GetRefereshedList, 5000);

and in GetRefreshedList ..you can use $.ajax() method to get the new list from the server and update the view all on the client-side.

If you can share your code, I can expand it a bit more.

Comment: I tried it, if I use setInterval("GetList()", 5000); with quotes I get "GetList()" is undefined, and if I drop the quotes I get another error message asking me if I forgot the quotes.